# Bottom-aligning columns with tikzposter and TexLive 2022

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, xparse, tikzposter

The script found in [Bottom-aligning columns with tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175753/bottom-aligning-columns-with-tikzposter) works fine with TexLive 2021. However, since TexLive 2022, the script raises `! Missing number, treated as zero. \xparse function is not expandable` when calling `\column{0.4}`.

Is there a way to fix it?

Here is the minimal `main.tex` to reproduce the issue.

```tex
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\title{Tikz Poster Example}
\usetheme{Board}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colalign]{myposter} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175753/bottom-aligning-columns-with-tikzposter

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

    \column{0.4}
    \block{More text}{Text and more text}

    \column{0.6}
    \block{Something else}{Here, \blindtext \vspace{4cm}}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well things like `\setcounter{my@block}{\ref{my@numblocks\alph{my@column}}}` won't work anymore. \ref is now protected.